# Send JSon data from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I'm trying to post an array in javascript to php session variable using JSon. I searched a lot, there are 3 ways to post; HTML form Posting Request, AJAX and cookies. I want to post by posting request, in my script I convert my array to a JSon object no problem. Then I tried to send it to php page like this;

```
$('#firstConfirmButton').click(function(){  

    var json_text = JSON.stringify(ordersArray, null);
    alert(json_text.toString());

    request= new XMLHttpRequestObject();
    request.open("POST", "test.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    request.send(json_text);

});
```

In test.php I tried to get array by using file_get_contents('php://input') but it did not work. When i try to echo son_text, it shows "firstConfirmButton=" instead of array content. What should I do?

```
<?php

   require("includes/db.php");
   require("includes/functions.php");

    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['firstConfirmButton'])) { 

        $json_text = \file_get_contents('php://input');
        echo $json_text; 

    }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery, use ajax functions of jQuery for better compatibility on browsers:

```
$('#firstConfirmButton').click(function(){  

    $.post("test.php", { data: ordersArray }, function(response){                    
               // success callback
               // response variable can be used for response from PHP, if any
    });
});
```

In your PHP Code:

```
print_r($_POST['data']);
```

Please note that `ordersArray` should be valid JSON. You can then use variables in PHP as per your need.

Comment: thnks for reply but what do u mean with "success callback", is there any need to code in that block?

Comment: if you want to return something in response & based upon that you want to do something, that code will go to success callback. `response` variable will provide you response data.

Comment: I can not send a succesful request with the code above although my ordersArray is valid. I try first ordeArray as an array then secondly I used var json_text = JSON.stringify(ordersArray, null); and send json_text as data. But both of them did not work.

Comment: No error in the console, I use Safari also tried in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate Apul's answer but you have missed somethings that are causing the problem, do this:

## Method 1 (Recommended):

```
$('#firstConfirmButton').click(function(){  

var json_text = JSON.stringify(ordersArray, null);
alert(json_text.toString());

var request;
var XMLHttpFactories = [
    function () {return new XMLHttpRequest()},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}
];

function createXMLHTTPObject() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    for (var i=0;i<XMLHttpFactories.length;i++) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = XMLHttpFactories[i]();
        }
        catch (e) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
function sendRequest(url,callback,postData) {
    var req = createXMLHTTPObject();
    if (!req) return;
    var method = (postData) ? "POST" : "GET";
    req.open(method,url,true);
    req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
    if (postData)
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','text/json');
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (req.readyState != 4) return;
            if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
                alert('HTTP error ' + req.status);
                return;
            }
        callback(req);
    }
    if (req.readyState == 4) return;
    req.send(postData);
}

});
```

And finally call the `sendRequest` function like this:

```
sendRequest('file.txt',handleRequest,ordersArray);
function handleRequest(req) {
    var writeroot = [some element];
    writeroot.innerHTML = req.responseText;
}
```

## Method 2 (No issue in using):

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","demo_post2.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/json");
xmlhttp.send(ordersArray);
```

## To read the data in PHP:

```
$json_text = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo json_decode($json_text); //I have changed the send data from `json_text` to the direct non-Stringified json object, the `ordersArray`.
```

Difference between the two is of scalability.

*Note: Difference between my and Apul's answer is of jQuery, I didn't used it, he did.*

Comment: how should I handle this in the php side, I still can not send the data.

Comment: Also your \`\\` could be buggy at the start of `file_get_contents`.

Comment: aprecieate for your interest, I have one more question. I tried second method,in your code there is  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; what "myDiv" refers for my code, is it firstConfirmButton? and what does this code do exactly?

Comment: Aray, it's just a line to tell you that the output from the request that youa re taking is under xmlhttp.responseText

Answer (score 0):

Apul is right about using an AJAX library.
On the PHP side, I 'receive' the data using

`$value = urldecode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am still trying to solve this problem and I think I have some progress. Maybe somebody else will have same problem, I hope it will help him. Firstly I changed my javascript code to that, especially adding "async:false" saved my life because without this update, Safari and Firefoc can not post any Json variable to php(Chrome is ok). It took my 2 days to learn this.

```
$('#firstConfirmButton').click(function(){  


    var my_json_val = JSON.stringify(ordersArray, null);
    alert(my_json_val.toString());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gazanfer.php",
        data: my_json_val,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        success:  function(data){
            //alert("---"+data);
        alert("Settings has been updated successfully.");
        window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }); 

});
```

Now posting is ok but still I can not read the data on php side. I don't know why, here is my php code. Is there any idea?

```
<?php


    require("includes/db.php");
    require("includes/functions.php");

    $my_json_encoded = $_POST['data'];
    $my_json_val = json_decode($my_json_encoded);
    echo $my_json_val;

?>
```